# Is it possible to add a "Show All" option to the pagination of a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView control setup like this:

```
<asp:GridView
    ID="UserList"
    AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="20"
    runat="server">

    ...
```

I would like to be able to control the "AllowPaging" parameter of this control in my VB code, but I'm not sure how to add a "Show All" option to the page list at the bottom of the control.  This is possible?  Am I not thinking about this problem in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You create a `<PagerTemplate>` and include the show all option. In one of our applications, we have a `DropDownList` with pages sizes. We capture the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event and set the `GridView`'s page size.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check the design view of that page, hove over the grid view and an arrow pops up at the top right. That should have some options if I understood you correctly